# Can not put an entity class in the getEntityClass manager method

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin

I would like to create a ClientLimitHistoryManager that will implement SimpleManager, but there is a problem with getEntityClass() because the class I'm trying to return does not like the compiler.

```
abstract class SimpleManager<T> {
    @PersistenceContext
    open lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    abstract fun <T> getEntityClass(): Class<T>
}



@Stateless
open class ClientLimitHistoryManager : SimpleManager<ClientLimit>() {
    override fun <ClientLimit> getEntityClass(): Class<ClientLimit> {
        return ClientLimit::class
    }
}
```

[image: screen with error]

I tried also with ClientLimit::class.java but nothing better result.

Is it possible to do it in Kotlin somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the generic multiple times.
That's where the reified type parameter error came from.

```
    abstract fun <T> getEntityClass(): Class<T>
```

should change to:

```
    abstract fun getEntityClass(): Class<T>
```

Because the T generic has already been declared when you wrote `abstract class SimpleManager<T>`

Then fix the subclass by changing

```
override fun <ClientLimit> getEntityClass(): Class<ClientLimit> {
    return ClientLimit::class
}
```

to

```
override fun getEntityClass(): Class<ClientLimit> {
    return ClientLimit::class
}
```

This way the reified type parameter error will go away and you will be left with the "Type mismatch." error.

Change the `ClientLimit::class` to `ClientLimit::class.java` and you are good to go.